# 2018 Tour De France - schedule with start times?

Tags: tour-de-france

Is anybody aware of a source for a 2018 Tour De France schedule, including start times?  I can find many sites that have the schedule per day but none seem to include the start times for each stage.

Answer (score 3):

The [Official Tour de France website](http://www.letour.fr/) has this information. Alas, it's unlinkable but:

1. Select "Route 2018" from the top menu bar.
2. Click the stage you're interested in.
3. Scroll down to just above the map, where you see "Sport Side"<sup>*</sup>.
4. Click "Time schedule".

Times are given in local time, which is CEST (GMT+2).

---

<sup>* The TdF website has always had somewhat idiosyncratic English. I don't know why they don't just get a native speaker to write their English content.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is it:

---

https://www.cyclingweekly.com/news/racing/tour-de-france/tour-de-france-live-tv-guide-233516

Tour de France 2018 TV Guide

1
Saturday, July 7
ITV4: 9:30 am - 3:15 pm
Eurosport 1: 9:30 am - 3:15 pm

2
Sunday, July 8
ITV4: 12:00 pm - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1:  12:00 pm - 5:00 pm

3
Monday, July 9
ITV4: 1:45 pm - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1:  2:00 pm - 5:00 pm

4
Tuesday, July 10
ITV4: 12:00 pm - 5:15 pm
Eurosport 1:  11:45 am - 5:15 pm

5
Wednesday, July 11
ITV4: 11:15 am - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1:  11:00 am - 5:00 pm

6
Thursday, July 12
ITV4: 12:00 pm - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1: 12:00 pm - 5:00 pm

7
Friday, July 13
ITV4: 11:00 am - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1: 11:00 am - 5:00 pm

8
Saturday, July 14
ITV4: 10:30 am - 3:00 pm
Eurosport 1: 10:30 am - 3:00 pm

9
Sunday, July 15
ITV4: 11:30 am - 3:00 pm
Eurosport 1: 11:30 am - 3:00 pm

Rest Day    Monday, July 16

10
Tuesday, July 17
ITV4: 9:30 am - 5:30 pm
Eurosport 1: 9:30 am - 5:30 pm

11
Wednesday, July 18
ITV4: 12:45 pm - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1: 12:45 pm - 5:00 pm

12
Thursday, July 19
ITV4: 11:00 am - 5:15 pm
Eurosport 1: 11:00 am - 5:15 pm

13
Friday, July 20
ITV4: 12:30 pm - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1: 12:30 pm - 5:00 pm

14
Saturday, July 21
ITV4: 12:00 pm - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1: 12:00 pm - 5:00 pm

15
Sunday, July 22
ITV4: 12:00 pm - 5:15 pm
Eurosport 1: 12:00 pm - 5:15 pm

Rest Day    Monday, July 23

16
Tuesday, July 24
ITV4: 10:15 am - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1:  10:15 am - 5:00 pm

17
Wednesday, July 25
ITV4: 2:00 pm - 5:00 pm
Eurosport 1: 2:00 pm - 5:00 pm

18
Thursday, July 26
ITV4: 12:45 pm - 5:15 pm
Eurosport 1: 12:45 pm - 5:15 pm

19
Friday, July 27
ITV4: 11:00 am - 5:15 pm
Eurosport 1: 11:00 am - 5:15 pm

20
Saturday, July 28
ITV4: 10:45 am - 4:45 pm
Eurosport 1: 10:45 am - 4:45 pm

21
Sunday, July 29
ITV: 3:30 pm - 7:00 pm
Eurosport 1: 3:30 pm - 7:00 pm

---

Times seem to be in Central European Time, which is GMT+2.  For anybody watching in the U.S. Eastern Time (EST) zone it seems subtracting 6 hours provides a correct time adjustment.  For example, the 1st stage estimated finish time adjustment would be:

3:15 pm (stated above) Central European Time - 6 hours = 9:15 am U.S. Eastern Time

If anybody more familiar with time zone changes than I am could verify this that would be great.

Now if I can only find a way to view this over the internet without signing up for a paid internet TV package . . .

Comment: I'd be surprised if the ITV times were CST. they're much more likely to be BST (they're in the UK)

Comment: @ChrisH And France is currently on CEST, not CET.